# Altering NHibernate config file using c# linq

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, nhibernate

let us consider the following web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name='proxyfactory.factory_class'>NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle
      </property>
      <property name="connection.provider">
       NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
      </property>

     <property name="connection.connection_string">
         Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
      </property>
      <property name="dialect">
        NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect
      </property>
      <property name="show_sql">
        false
      </property>
      <property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">none</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
   <startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <qualifyAssembly partialName="MySql.Data" fullName="MySql.Data, Version=5.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```

My query is to change the value in the  tag

**old value:**

```
<property name="connection.provider">
       NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
      </property>
```

**new value**

```
<property name="connection.provider">
      Sample.DriverConnectionProvider
      </property>
```

For that I used:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("path to webconfig");

 var xElems = from x in doc.Descendants()
            where x.Name.LocalName == "property name=\"connection.provider\""
                  select x;

                foreach (var xElem in xElems)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(xElem.Attribute("name"));
                }
```

But while I view the document I get the view in xdoc as:

```
//<property name="connection.provider" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is the issue? The xdoc result is what I expect it to be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2";
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(....);
var prop = xDoc.Descendants(ns+"property")
               .First(p=>p.Attribute("name").Value=="connection.provider");

prop.Value = "Sample.DriverConnectionProvider";
```

Comment: can we get the namespace value through this query XNamespace ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;

Comment: `var ns = xDoc.Descendants().First(x => x.Name.LocalName == "hibernate-configuration").Name.Namespace;`